# java.sql.Timestamp: changing timezone of Timestamp

Tags: java

How can I change timezone of a java.sql.Timestamp object which was initially, instantiated to CST, to GMT?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`java.sql.Timestamp` objects don't *have* time zones - they are instants in time, like `java.util.Date`.

If you're thinking of them as being in a particular time zone, you may either be getting confused due to misleading output (e.g. something automatically converting that instant into a local time using a default time zone) or you may have created the data in an inappropriate way. The answer you need will depend on the details of your situation.

For example, if you just want to *display* a `Timestamp` value in a particular time zone, you can use `SimpleDateFormat`, set the time zone appropriately, and just format the `Timestamp` (as it extends `Date`). I don't believe that will allow you to display as much precision as the timestamp stores internally, but that *may* not be a problem for you.

If your data has been *created* incorrectly then there may or may not be a way to "correct" it - there may be some ambiguities due to daylight saving time changes, for example. However, the more we know about it the better we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks, Jon for the answer,but there is getTimezoneOffset(), a deprecated method in Timestamp which returns the offset from GMT in minutes, in my case it returns it to be 360 minutes. The desired result was to change this to 0, which will be the case with a GMT Timestamp.

Comment: @abson: `getTimezoneOffset` is inherited from `Date` - it's *always* relative to the system default time zone. It's not part of the object at all, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: The timezone offset is definitely affecting the result.  I have two timestamps in the DB.  One before DST and one after DST.  If I create a Calendar object using Timestamp's getTime() as its constructor parameter, it is fine for the before DST timestamp but not the after DST timestamp.  It is incorrectly "correcting" it by one hour despite using Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")) to instantiate the Calendar object

Comment: My problem appears to be an Oracle peculiarity.  Seems you need to pass a calendar object with the required timezone when getting the timestamp (e.g. resultSet.getTimestamp("last_update_time_utc", calendar)) Here's a useful link explaining stuff: http://puretech.paawak.com/2010/11/02/how-to-handle-oracle-timestamp-with-timezone-from-java/

Comment: Archive.org backup for the previous comment's now-dead link: https://web.archive.org/web/20130924231308/http://puretech.paawak.com/2010/11/02/how-to-handle-oracle-timestamp-with-timezone-from-java/

Answer (score 9):

Some Timestamp constructors do depend on the default timezone.
One way to avoid this is to use the constructor that takes a long:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
Timestamp.valueOf("2016-10-26 23:00:00").getTime()

res16: Long = 1477522800000 // This is what we want

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1"))
Timestamp.valueOf("2016-10-26 23:00:00").getTime()

res14: Long = 1477526400000

new Timestamp(OffsetDateTime.of(2016,10,26,23,0,0,0,ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant.toEpochMilli).getTime

res15: Long = 1477522800000 // We get the same result at in GMT
```

Comment: The Javadoc on Timestamp doesn't mention it, but the underlying cause is it extends the Date object and uses it for construction.